# count total amount of numbers of each line in a file

Tags: java

I'm trying read a file and store the numbers into a 2D array. I'm using:

```
int lines = (int) Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).count();
```

to get the total amount of lines in the file to create my 2D array, the problem is i cant find a way to check if a line has some extra numbers.

> 67,1,43
>
> 13,37,61,3
>
> 31,73,7

With the example above the program will work just fine but I want to stop if the numbers of each line aren't even. Is there a specific way to count the elements of one line and compare them to the elements of the other lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the lines, check the array length and just store the maximum length somewhere.

For example:

```java
int maxLength = 0;
Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> {
    int lineLength = line.split(",").length;
    if(lineLength > maxLength) {
        maxLength = lineLength;
    }
});
```